# What do historians do when limited sources are available?

Tags: historiography

Although my area of history is focusing on 1980s and 1990s, in general, when you're studying an era of history or a particular topic and there are little to no sources available (for example, areas of Ancient Egyptian medicine, some Roman-era politics, or certain vehicle specifications for cars of the 1980s/1990s etc.) what are good ways to deal with this?

I often tend to use compare-and-contrast and primary/secondary sources if I can; Wikipedia is a tertiary source isn't it?

In general, would a historian focusing on a topic area skip over a subtopic or continue until they find sources relating to it?

I'm not sure how to do this when researching a historical topic; no current research topics at the moment.

Comment: First, you make me feel old and probably a lot of others on this site because your "history" is my childhood. Wikipedia is a tertiary source. Typically, I start looking for contextual clues in sources that can be related, or you can post here and help crowd source your answer. If you're question is on 80's/90's, I bet most people here can speak from experience and then you'd have a primary source.

Comment: It sounds like you're only doing online research. Is your local library barren of sources? Our city's reference archives would still have, say, publications from the '80s and '90s with vehicle information.

Comment: Are you asking about when no sources exist at all, or you don't have sources readily available? I'm sure somewhere there's specs for vehicles from the 80s and 90s, even if it's just in someone's head.

Comment: It is indeed striking to me that there is any idea at all that one can do work purely on-line and acquire/access primary sources... As opposed to "on the ground" work, physically going to physical places and looking at physical objects. :)

Comment: Archaeology teaches a lot about the past, even the recent past, and there are lots of alternative methods in disciplines like human anthropology, such as genetic analysis and linguistic reconstruction, which can provide information on population movements, lifestyle, etc. Whether they count as history or not is a different question: for some, history only starts with written records.

Comment: I suspect you can get any auto specs you might need from [Mitchell manuals](https://www.eautorepair.net/app/YearsMakes.asp) at least for any car that was common on roads in the US